# Flattening and unflattening an Image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have a small 80x80 pixel grayscale image as shown below;

[image]

I use the follow code to flatten this image into a vector;

```
o = numpy.array(a)
o = o.flatten()
o = o/256
```

Where ***a*** is the image shown above. I then want to convert this back to an image (I plan on doing some work in between but that's beside the point atm - I only read from the pixels, not change them). To do this I've tried;

```
tmp = test_set_x[i]
tmp = tmp * 256
tmp.shape = (tmp.size//80, 80)
img = Image.fromarray(tmp, 'L')
img.save('imgOut' + str(cntr) + '.bmp')
```

However, this seems to give me files like this;

[image]

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can you tell what is the `dtype` of original image which is o in your case. Also, see what is the value you are getting when you pass numpy array to the function of `np.max`.

Comment: In case you are using python2 could you try to change your 3rd line to `o = o / 255.0` to force float division?

Answer (score 0):

You can get already flattened array as this:

```
size = a.size
o = np.fromstring(a.tobytes())

# Do on o whatever you like and then:
a = Image.frombytes("L", size, o.astype(np.int8).tostring())
```

Should be even faster than getting a new array pixel by pixel.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking just to flatten the image array and then perform array operations (changing pixel values etc), then `scipy` has pretty direct modules available.

For example, using [scipy.ndimage.imread](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.imread.html) you can directly read and flatten array. Even select different modes if desirable.

The returned numpy array is available for any  intermediate manipulation of pixels.

Once done, we can use [scipy.misc.imsave](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imsave.html) you can save the image.

Here is a sample code that reads your image, adds (0.5 value) to each pixel (thus lightining it little bit) and then saves the file back.

```
from scipy.ndimage import imread
from  scipy.misc import imsave

#read and flatten image
a = imread('sample.png' , flatten = True, mode=None)

#Add 0.5 to numpy array to lighten it.
a = a * 0.5

#save the modified pixel array
imsave('out.png', a)
```

**numpy array data And Image**

```
>>> a
array([[  36.,   36.,   36., ...,   17.,   18.,   18.],
       [  36.,   36.,   36., ...,   22.,   22.,   20.],
       [  37.,   37.,   37., ...,   26.,   25.,   24.],
       ..., 
       [ 110.,  119.,  130., ...,   17.,   17.,   18.],
       [ 115.,  106.,  113., ...,   14.,   15.,   16.],
       [ 119.,  114.,  101., ...,   15.,   13.,   13.]], dtype=float32)
```

[image]

**Image after modifying numpy array**

```
>>> a.shape
(80, 80)
>>> a = a * 0.5
>>> a
array([[ 18. ,  18. ,  18. , ...,   8.5,   9. ,   9. ],
       [ 18. ,  18. ,  18. , ...,  11. ,  11. ,  10. ],
       [ 18.5,  18.5,  18.5, ...,  13. ,  12.5,  12. ],
       ..., 
       [ 55. ,  59.5,  65. , ...,   8.5,   8.5,   9. ],
       [ 57.5,  53. ,  56.5, ...,   7. ,   7.5,   8. ],
       [ 59.5,  57. ,  50.5, ...,   7.5,   6.5,   6.5]], dtype=float32)
>>> ===============================
```

[image]